# Unity 2D collision not stopping if other gameobject destroys

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision, destroy, collider

I m coding a 2d platform game. In the game, there are allies and enemies walks toward each other. If they collide each other, their own timer script starts countdown and the health reducing by the time as periods. If a characters health equals to zero, i destroy that gameobject. I add some booleans each character to detect they are colliding each other or not. While colliding both gameobjects, if one **destroys**, other colliding gameobject still continius colliding, although there is no colliding object. This happens just other colliding object is destroyed.

```
public float  setSpeed;
public bool enemyColliding;

float speed;

void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    speed= setSpeed;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (speed,GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
    if (enemyColliding) {
        attackAnimation ();
    } 
    else
    {
       walkAnimation();
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "dusman" /*enemy*/ ) {
        enemyColliding= true;
    }

}
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.tag=="dusman" /*enemy*/) {
        enemyColliding= false;
    }
}
void attackAnimation()
{
    Animator animator = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ();
    animator.runtimeAnimatorController = Resources.Load ("AllyWr2AttackAnim") as RuntimeAnimatorController;
}
void walkAnimation ()
{
    Animator animator = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ();
    animator.runtimeAnimatorController = Resources.Load ("AllyWr2WalkAnim") as RuntimeAnimatorController;
}
```

Any help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D coll)
{
   enemyColliding= false;
}
```

try this

Comment: Thanks for answer. There are more then one different gameobjects. it detects others if i do it.

Comment: If Im right, when you deleting gameobject with hp < 0, they colliding yet and OnTriggerExit2D wasn't called. It call's after deleting and coll in OnTriggerExit2D should be null. Check this. if its true, you can use it in if statement

Comment: another way is to change position of gameobject outside gamefield and then delete it. hack)